# Remove vertical label axis of Multiple-Value-Axes amchart

Tags: amcharts

I am okay all the line types under graph but I don't need their vertical represents 
morever I have only one axis and yaxis values in my chart but multiple lines.

How can I customize this amchart sample or find any suitable chart for my need?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Practically every component in the chart has a `disabled` property that you can use to hide or reveal. To get rid of the line and labels, simply set the `disabled` property to true to remove them, similar to how the grid was disabled:

```
  valueAxis.renderer.line.disabled = true; //disables axis line
  valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true; //disables labels
  valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;  //disables grid
```

Demo:

```js
// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Increase contrast by taking evey second color
chart.colors.step = 2;

// Add data
chart.data = generateChartData();

// Create axes
var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());

// Create series
function createAxisAndSeries(field, name, bullet) {
  var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
  
  var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
  series.dataFields.valueY = field;
  series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
  series.strokeWidth = 2;
  series.yAxis = valueAxis;
  series.name = name;
  series.tooltipText = "{name}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";
  series.tensionX = 0.8;
  
  var interfaceColors = new am4core.InterfaceColorSet();
  
  switch(bullet) {
    case "triangle":
      var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.Bullet());
      bullet.width = 12;
      bullet.height = 12;
      bullet.horizontalCenter = "middle";
      bullet.verticalCenter = "middle";
      
      var triangle = bullet.createChild(am4core.Triangle);
      triangle.stroke = interfaceColors.getFor("background");
      triangle.strokeWidth = 2;
      triangle.direction = "top";
      triangle.width = 12;
      triangle.height = 12;
      break;
    case "rectangle":
      var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.Bullet());
      bullet.width = 10;
      bullet.height = 10;
      bullet.horizontalCenter = "middle";
      bullet.verticalCenter = "middle";
      
      var rectangle = bullet.createChild(am4core.Rectangle);
      rectangle.stroke = interfaceColors.getFor("background");
      rectangle.strokeWidth = 2;
      rectangle.width = 10;
      rectangle.height = 10;
      break;
    default:
      var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
      bullet.circle.stroke = interfaceColors.getFor("background");
      bullet.circle.strokeWidth = 2;
      break;
  }
  
  valueAxis.renderer.line.disabled = true;
  valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;
  valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
}

createAxisAndSeries("visits", "Visits",  "circle");
createAxisAndSeries("views", "Views",  "triangle");
createAxisAndSeries("hits", "Hits",  "rectangle");

// Add legend
chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();

// Add cursor
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();

// generate some random data, quite different range
function generateChartData() {
  var chartData = [];
  var firstDate = new Date();
  firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() - 100);
  firstDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

  var visits = 1600;
  var hits = 2900;
  var views = 8700;

  for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    // we create date objects here. In your data, you can have date strings
    // and then set format of your dates using chart.dataDateFormat property,
    // however when possible, use date objects, as this will speed up chart rendering.
    var newDate = new Date(firstDate);
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + i);

    visits += Math.round((Math.random()<0.5?1:-1)*Math.random()*10);
    hits += Math.round((Math.random()<0.5?1:-1)*Math.random()*10);
    views += Math.round((Math.random()<0.5?1:-1)*Math.random()*10);

    chartData.push({
      date: newDate,
      visits: visits,
      hits: hits,
      views: views
    });
  }
  return chartData;
}
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to display only one y-axis?

Comment: Of course it is. Please open a new question with more context instead of asking in an old question.

Comment: This is my code.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57406176/is-it-possible-to-display-only-one-y-axis-in-multi-value-amchart

Answer (score 0):

[image]

multiple-value-axes remove 3rd axis from chart.
Only two axis will show.