# Is it possible to display only one Y axis in Multi value amChart?

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I have an Multi Value AmChart where I'm sending dynamic values and is working as expected but as I'm sending the values dynamically which is of percentage value it doesn't require the Y-axis separately for all the lines . Only one y axis is enough for all the lines.

I'm able to disable the appearing y axis and and I also created a single y-axis (static y axis) but it is not synchronized with the series of chart.

```
trend() {
    this._chart = am4core.create( "trend_yield", am4charts.XYChart );
    this._chart.data = this._TChart;
    this._chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();

    this._selectedItems.forEach( selectedItem => {
        if ( selectedItem.id != 1 && selectedItem.id != 2 ) {
            this.createAxisAndSeries();

            let valueAxis = this._chart.yAxes.push( new am4charts.ValueAxis() );

            let series = this._chart.series.push( new am4charts.LineSeries() );
            series.dataFields.valueY = selectedItem.itemName;
            series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
            series.tensionX = 0.8;
            series.strokeWidth = 2;
            series.strokeOpacity = 5;
         //   series.yAxis = valueAxis;
            series.name = selectedItem.itemName;
            series.tooltipText = "{name}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";

            let interfaceColors = new am4core.InterfaceColorSet();
            let bullet = series.bullets.push( new am4charts.CircleBullet() );
            bullet.circle.stroke = interfaceColors.getFor( "background" );
            bullet.circle.strokeWidth = 2;

            valueAxis.renderer.line.disabled = true; //disables axis line
            valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;
            valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true; 
        }
    } );

    if ( this._selectedItems.length > 1 ) {
        let valueAxis = this._chart.yAxes.push( new am4charts.ValueAxis() );

        valueAxis.autoGridCount = false;
        valueAxis.max = 100;
        valueAxis.min = 0;
        valueAxis.unit = "%";
        valueAxis.unitPosition = "right";

        valueAxis.renderer.line.strokeOpacity = 1;
        valueAxis.renderer.line.strokeWidth = 1;
        valueAxis.renderer.line.stroke = am4core.color( "#3787ac" );

        // Enable export
        this._chart.exporting.menu = new am4core.ExportMenu();
        this._chart.exporting.filePrefix = "Yield Chart";
        this._chart.exporting.menu.items = [
            {
                "label": "...",
                "menu": [
                    { "type": "pdf", "label": "PDF" },
                    { "label": "Print", "type": "print" }
                ]
            }
        ];
    }
}

createAxisAndSeries() {
    this._chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
    this._chart.colors.step = 6;

    // Create axes
    let dateAxis = this._chart.xAxes.push( new am4charts.DateAxis() );
    dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0.5;
    dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 40;
    dateAxis.renderer.labels.template.location = 0.0001;
    dateAxis.renderer.minLabelPosition = 0.05;
    dateAxis.renderer.maxLabelPosition = 0.95;
    dateAxis.renderer.ticks.template.disabled = false;
    dateAxis.renderer.ticks.template.strokeOpacity = 1;
    dateAxis.renderer.ticks.template.stroke = am4core.color( "#495C43" );
    dateAxis.renderer.ticks.template.strokeWidth = 2;
    dateAxis.renderer.ticks.template.length = 10;
    dateAxis.renderer.ticks.template.location = 0.5;
    dateAxis.renderer.line.strokeOpacity = 1;
    dateAxis.renderer.line.strokeWidth = 1;
    dateAxis.renderer.line.stroke = am4core.color( "#3787ac" );
    dateAxis.startLocation = 0.5;
    dateAxis.endLocation = 0.5;
}
```

Comment: So you can simply create a single ValueAxis. Just move the let valueAxis = this._chart.yAxes.push( new am4charts.ValueAxis() ); line outside the forEach method.

Comment: But it doesnt sync with the all the values to one y axis.